# Cannot Set Up Git on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

I am very new and I was learning about github and how to install in my Ubuntu system from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-configure-and-use-git-on-ubuntu/). But I am facing this error (**error: key does not contain a section: –global**) It would be great to get some help on this.

Comment: `--global` (double dashes), not `-global`

Answer (score 1):

The code formatting on the website you linked to is a bit off / wrong unfortunately since they do not correctly format double-dashes in parameters (among other issues).

To setup your name and email address, you have to use the following commands (wot your own name and email address of course):

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

In any case, I'd recommend to use a better guide to get started with git. If you want to use mostly GitHub, maybe use their guide available at https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/quickstart.